# Put memcached on db or web server instance?

Tags: postgresql, nginx, memcached

For my Drupal-based site, I have an architecture with 3 instances running nginx, postgresql, & solr, respectively. I'd like to install Memcached. Should I put it on the nginx or postgresql server? What are the performance implications?

Comment: So far I have receive two answers with rather different advice. So I must rely on user votes and feedback to assess which answer to support. Please vote and comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Memcached is very light on CPU usage, so it is a great candidate to gobble up spare web server RAM. Also, you will scale out you web tier much more than your other tiers, and Memcached clustering can pool that RAM together into one logical cache.

If you have any spare RAM on the DB, it is almost always best for performance to let the DB gobble it up.

TL;DR Let DB have all of the RAM, colocate memcached on web tier.

Source: http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/NewHardware

Answer (score 1):

The best is to have a separate server (if you can do that).

Otherwise, it depends on your servers CPU & memory utilization and availability requirements. In general I would avoid running anything extra on a DB server machine...since DB is the foundation of the system and has to be available and performing well.

if your Solr server does not have high traffic an don't utilize much memory I'd put it in there. Memcached servers known to be light on CPU. Also you should estimate how much memory memcached instance will need...to make sure its enough on the server.